# How to check if a String can be formed from the characters of another String in Java?

Tags: java, string

A string is good if it can be formed by characters from chars. I want to return the sum of lengths of all good strings in words.

Input: words = ["cat","bt","hat","tree"], chars = "atach"

Output: 6

Explanation: 
The strings that can be formed are "cat" and "hat" so the answer is 3 + 3 = 6.

Below is the code that I have written.

```
class Solution
{
    public int countCharacters(String[] words, String chars) 
    {
        int k = 0, count = 0;
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
        {
            set.add(chars.charAt(i));
        }

        StringBuilder chrs = new StringBuilder();
        for(Character ch : set)
        { 
            chrs.append(ch);   
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            char[] ch = words[i].toCharArray();

            for(int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++)
            {
                if(chrs.contains("" + ch[j]))
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            if(k == words[i].length())
            {
                count+= k;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}

Output:
Line 24: error: cannot find symbol

                if(chrs.contains("" + ch[j]))
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong in accessing the character?

Comment: I changed my code, a little to eliminate the duplicates in 'chars' string.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues which I noticed is you are using `contains()` to compare a String and a character. But the `contains()` method is a Java method to check if String contains another substring or not.

**So you can solve this by converting the character to a string.**

Ex 1:

```
if(chars.contains(Character.toString(ch[j]))){
    k++;
} else {
}
```

Ex 2:

```
f(chars.contains(""+ch[j]))
{
    k++;
} else {
}
```

**Otherwise, You can compare if the string contains a char by using `indexOf()`. If the string isn't containing the char it return -1. Please refer bellow example.**

Ex:

```
if(chars.indexOf(ch[j])!=-1){
    k++;
} else {
}
```

Comment: I edited my code, a little. The error still persists.

Comment: This time the issue occurred because you are checking StringBuilder instead of String. You should have to convert the String builder to a String before using contains().  You can convert it as follows..

if(chrs.toString().contains("" + ch[j]))

Answer (score 0):

[`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) tells you if a *string* is contained in another *string*. But in your case `ch[j]` is not a string but a char, so you can't use `contains`.

Instead, use [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)), it returns `-1` if the char is not present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way is

```java
chars.contains("" + ch[i]);
```

Comment: I edited my code a little, but the error still persists. Please review my updated code

Comment: `chars` not `chrs` typo

Answer (score 0):

Here, `ch[j]` is not a string but a char, so you can't use contains as you've done. Instead, make the following change.

```
chars.contains(String.valueOf(ch[j]));
```